# what does this regex /.{2,}/ mean?

Tags: regex

I can't figure out this even after searching through examples of regex.
Can someone tell me what this expression means?

```
 /.{2,}/
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: This is a fantastic site for seeing what regular expressions mean: http://www.regexr.com

Answer (score 4):

Greedily match two or more of any characters **that are not a line separator, but...**.

**that will depend on your engine:**

- In PCRE, C#, Python, Ruby, the `.` matches any char that is not `\n`... Watch out, as that includes the carriage return `\r`
- In JavaScript and Java, the `.` matches any char that is not a line break character (`\n`, `\r`, paragraph separators)...

**`{2,}` is greedy (it eats up as many characters as possible)**

Note that the `{2,}` quantifier is "greedy": `.{2,}` will match as many characters as possible, and will only "give back characters" (backtrack) if necessary, for instance to allow the next token (if any) to match.

**`DOTALL` mode**

In `dotall` mode (which you turn on differently in various engine), the `.` will also match line separators.

- In most engines, this mode is activated by the `s` flag
- In Ruby, it is activated by the `m` flag

Comment: I appreciate your response. Basically I am trying to prevent customers injecting malicious code in my Customer Comment Form. The existing program only has /.{2,}/ in the Regex field. I would like to create a regex to only allow letters, numbers, commas,and periods. I would also like to limit the number of words to the comment area. So far I have this regex for characters allowed.   /^[a-zA-Z0-9'.,\s\-&\(\)]*$/  Do I need to keep /.{2,}/ in the field? Please help me put "characters allowed and words limit together" or suggest better ones. I am grateful for your help!

Comment: Your regex has a `*` quantifier so it will allow an empty string. If you want 2 or more, or between 5 and 10, use `{3,}` or `{5,10}`

Answer (score 3):

`.` matches any character except the newline character. Quoting from [MDN's RegExp page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_Special_Characters),

> (The decimal point) matches any single character except the newline character.

`{2,}` means two or more times.

So, the entire expression means that, "match any set of characters with length greater than or equal to 2"

Answer (score 2):

*`{ , }`* is a repetition quantifier. it is be used to specify ***how many times any token can be repeated against a successful match.***

quoting from `Limiting Repetition`: ([**HERE**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html))

*The syntax is `{min,max}`, where min is zero or a positive integer number indicating the minimum number of matches, and max is an integer equal to or greater than min indicating the maximum number of matches. **If the comma is present but max is omitted, the maximum number of matches is infinite**.*
Thus, `{2,}` would mean ***2 or more*** of the preceeding character.

the `.` represents any character (other than `line separator`) and the `forward-slashes` indicate the start and end of the regular expression.

---

**UPDATE:**

*`So far I have this regex for characters allowed. /^[a-zA-Z0-9'.,\s\-&()]*$/ Do I need to keep /.{2,}/ in the field?`*

`{a,b}` specifies minimum (through **a**) and maximum (through **b**) limits for a matching string. therefore, if you need to specify a min and/or max limit for your *`letters, numbers, commas,and periods`* you may enclose the **regex** for these characters in a ***group*** ( such as `[ ]`) and place `{ a, b}` right after this group, like this: `/^[a-z]{2,200}$/`. This will match a string of **2 to 200 lowercase alphabets.**

as for your `letters, numbers, commas,and periods`, in the regex `/^[a-zA-Z0-9'.,\s\-&()]*$/` you'll need to escape `.` and replace `*` with `{2,max-limit}`, as following:
`/^[a-zA-Z0-9'\.,\s\-&()]{2,20}$/`

--> [**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/eM8oZ4/1)

Comment: I tried the code /^[a-zA-Z0-9'\.,\s\-&()]{2,20}$/ you gave me , but it did not limit the word count. The other parts of it work ok to filter unwanted characters. I appreciate your help so far !!

Comment: see the `DEMO` link in the answer. in that page, try to enter more than 20 characters and the result (on the bottom right side of the page) will **not** match anything. therefore a **null match** could at as a check for the text entered. between 2 and 20, both inclusive, the match returns a character. maybe, ***(insert `(` and `)` around the square brackets in the regex pattern)*** to allow grouping. maybe due to lack of **grouping** there's no return value from the match.